# what is the best way to add age restrictions to your app using xcode and swift

Tags: swift, xcode, protocols, code-signing, guard

I need to put an age requirement on the app i am currently building and im looking for opinions on what you guys think would be the most efficient way to add this into the code. Should i use a guard let on the sign up screen or protocol?

Comment: Try to use social logins like Facebook, Google. From there you might get the age of the user so you can restrict them over there itself.

Comment: If you don't want to require FB/Google login you can also have a check box or a button "I agree that I am older than x yrs old" on your signup page. A date picker is also a possibility where users enter their birthday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have two options like first integrate some Socials like [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift) or [Google Integration](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in)

If you prefer not to use any social Logins then best way would come to allow user to select his/her birthday using PickerView.

Once the birthdate is set from pickerView, simply use that date to calculate the Age of the user using **following Code**

```
func findAgeFromBirthDate(_ birthDate:Date) ->Int {
    let now = Date();
    let calendar = Calendar.current;

    let ageComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: birthDate, to: now);
    let age = ageComponents.year!;
    print(age);
    return age;
}
```

**And Use it like to restrict the User:**

```
if age < 13{
  print("You are not allowed to use this")
}else{
  print("You are welcome")
}
```

**Second Option Would be:**

Give a Checkbox kind of button in App, This would help the user to tick or Un-tick if his/her age is greater than your restricted age or not.

Something like this:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome thanks for your feedback i like the check box idea too haha

Comment: Pleasure helping you buddy.